# проблема с запуском ассемблер через DOSBox на Mac m1

Tags: ассемблер, arm, dos

Есть код на ассемблере

```
Include io.asm
sstack SEGMENT STACK
          DB 128 DUP (?)
sstack ENDS
sdata SEGMENT
HI     DB 'Hello!','$'
aHI   DW HI
sdata ENDS
scode SEGMENT
         ASSUME CS:scode, DS:sdata, SS:sstack
START:
         MOV AX, sdata
         MOV DS, AX
         MOV DX, aHI
         OUTSTR
         FINISH
scode ENDS
END START
```

при запуске его через nasm в DOSBox

```
nasm name.asm
```

выдает ошибки
[image: ошибка]

запуск происходит через DOSBox на Mac m1(тоесть arm архитектуре). DOSBox версии 0.83.25
Помогите понять в чем проблема